# Cython project cannot import (unknown location)

Tags: python, cython

I am working on a python project, where it is calling a C routine and I am interfacing it with Cython. Here is the file directory structure:

```
pyfracdiff
├── src
|   ├── fracdiff.h
|   ├── fdcore.c
├── __init__.py
├── fracdiff.pxd
├── fracdiff.pyx
├── main.py
└── setup.py
```

Here is the setup.py

```
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np

ext = Extension("pyfracdiff", 
                sources=['fracdiff.pyx',
                         'src/fdcore.c'],
                include_dirs=['src/',
                              np.get_include(),
                              '/usr/share/R/include/'],
                define_macros=[('NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API', 'NPY_1_7_API_VERSION')],
                headers=['src/*.h',
                         '/usr/share/R/include/Rmath.h'])

setup(ext_modules=cythonize(ext))
```

I ran with `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` in the project directory which worked and compiled with no error. The directory structure becomes

```
pyfracdiff
├── build
|   ├── lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
|   |   ├── pyfracdiff.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
├── src
|   ├── fracdiff.h
|   ├── fdcore.c
├── __init__.py
├── fracdiff.c
├── pyfracdiff.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
├── fracdiff.pxd
├── fracdiff.pyx
├── main.py
└── setup.py
```

When I go one directory up (outside of the pyfracdiff directory) and ran `from pyfracdiff.fracdiff import fracdf_py` it throws an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyfracdiff.fracdiff'`, but `import pyfracdiff` will execute. The init py file is empty.

Did I do something wrong in terms of file structure, `setup.py` or how I ran the import?

Comment: Python (and probably Cython) doesn't care about the current working directory when resolving imports but only about the directories in `sys.path` which are used as roots for searching modules and packages.

Comment: "When I go one directory up (outside of the pyfracdiff directory) and ran from pyfracdiff.fracdiff import fracdf_py" - this doesn't appear to have anything to do with Cython. The apparent problem is that the `pyfracdiff` package is not found in the first place, because "going one directory up" doesn't change `sys.path`, and therefore doesn't change where Python looks for absolute imports. Depending on how Python was launched, `sys.path` may or may not contain a `'.'` or `''` entry.

Comment: The parent directory of `pyfracdiff` is in `sys.path`, and in fact, `import pyfracdiff` will execute, but `from pyfracdiff import fracdiff` will fail.